# JqGrid Does not Work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am Working in Asp.net mvc4 I am try to Include a jqgrid in it, But when i run the program it will not show anything Please help me to solve this

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/RGStyle.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Styles/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Script/JQGrid/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Script/JQGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Script/JQGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <link href="../../Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <h>list Details</h>
</head>
<body>



 <table id="tblJQGrid">
                </table>


 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid({
             url: 'list/Getlist_Details',
             datatype: "json",
             mtype: 'GET',
             colNames: ['Period', 'Year', 'Entity', 'SubmitStatus', 'SubmittedOn'],
             colModel: [
                { name: 'Period', index: 'Period', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
                { name: 'Year', index: 'Year', width: 150 },
                { name: 'Entity', index: 'Entity', width: 150 },
                { name: 'SubmitStatus', index: 'SubmitStatus', width: 100 },
                { name: 'SubmittedOn', index: 'SubmittedOn', width: 80, align: "right" },
                 ],
             rowNum: 10,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "CheckList  Details",
             scrollOffset: 0
         });
     });
    </script>
    </body>
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using X.Y.Controllers;
using X.Y;

namespace X.Y.Controllers
{
    public class listController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /DelegateChecklist/
        Common com = new Common();
        CheckListAssign ck = new CheckListAssign();
        public listController()
        {
            com.Load_Labels();


        }

        public ActionResult CMS_Checklist()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult Getlist_Details()
        {
            List<X.Models.list_Model> checklistsend = new List<Models.list_Model>();
            checklistsend.Add(new X.Models.list_Model()
            {
                Period="Feb",
                Year="2010",
                Entity="ABC",
                SubmitStatus="null",
                SubmittedOn="2014"


            });

            checklistsend.Add(new X.Models.list_Model()
            {
                Period = "Mar",
                Year = "2010",
                Entity = "ABC",
                SubmitStatus = "null",
                SubmittedOn = "2014"


            });
            checklistsend.Add(new X.Models.list_Model()
            {
                Period = "Apr",
                Year = "2010",
                Entity = "ABC",
                SubmitStatus = "null",
                SubmittedOn = "2014"


            });

            var checklistReturn = Json(checklistsend, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
            return checklistReturn;
        }


    }
}
```

**Modal**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace X.Y.Models
{
    public class list_Model
    {
        public string Period { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Entity { get; set; }
        public string SubmitStatus {get;set;}
        public string SubmittedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When i run the program only i get the title of the page. i did not get any jqgrid.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you even hitting the `Getlist_Details()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i had found the answer 
the problem is in document.ready function , when i remove it it works fine

```
     $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid({
         url: 'list/Getlist_Details',
         datatype: "json",
         mtype: 'GET',
         colNames: ['Period', 'Year', 'Entity', 'SubmitStatus', 'SubmittedOn'],
         colModel: [
            { name: 'Period', index: 'Period', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
            { name: 'Year', index: 'Year', width: 150 },
            { name: 'Entity', index: 'Entity', width: 150 },
            { name: 'SubmitStatus', index: 'SubmitStatus', width: 100 },
            { name: 'SubmittedOn', index: 'SubmittedOn', width: 80, align: "right" },
             ],
         rowNum: 10,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "CheckList  Details",
         scrollOffset: 0
     });
```

Comment: Typically one should place the code in `<head>` and use `document.ready` over the code. If you mix scripts and HTML fragments in `<body>` you should of cause not want for ready of parent element in JavaScript code. So `document.ready` is very useful in `<head>` of HTML file, but should be not used in scripted inserted directly in the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that if you want to fill **JQrid** with data you should pass particular `Json` collection to it. There are 2 ways of how you can do it.

### First Way

If you using **default JQgrid settings** you can pass this collection to `Json()` `Controller` method:

```
  public class Row
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<string> cell { get; set; }

        public Row()
        {
            cell = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public class JqgridData
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int records { get; set; }
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; }

        public JqgridData()
        {
            rows = new List<Row>();
        }
    }
```

Where `cell` is just a `string array` of your `list_Model` fields.

### Second Way

You can init **JQgrid** with different Bindings and make it populate your collection data.

Then you should change **JQgrid** defaults like this:

```
$.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    jsonReader: {
        root: "Elements",
        page: "PageSelected",
        total: "PagesAll",
        records: "RowsAll",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "Id"
    },
    prmNames:
        {
            sort: "SortField",
            page: "SelectedPage",
            rows: "RowsOnPage",
            order: "SortDirection",
            search: "Search",
            nd: null,
        }
});
```

And then you can pass this class to `Json()` `Controller` method:

```
 public class Set<T>
    {
        public Set(List<T> elements, int rowsOnPage, int pageSelected, int rowsAll)
        {
            Elements = elements;
            PageSelected = pageSelected;
            RowsOnPage = rowsOnPage;
            RowsAll = rowsAll;
            PagesAll = (rowsAll % RowsOnPage == 0) 
            ? rowsAll / RowsOnPage 
            : rowsAll / RowsOnPage + 1; ;
        }
        public int RowsOnPage { get; set; }
        public List<T> Elements { get; set; }
        public int? RowsAll { get; set; }
        public int PageSelected { get; set; }
        public int PagesAll { get; set; }
    }
```

You can use it in your `Controller` like this:

```
 return Json(new Set<list_Model>(checklistsend, 
 checklistsend.Count(),
 1,    
 checklistsend.Count()),
 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But you should remember that **field names in your Class should match field in your Jqgrid difinition**.

Comment: Thanks for your valid information, the problem is my server side function is never hitting , in my client side i am trying to call a function with  url: 'list/Getlist_Details', this url but the function in server side never called. please help me to solving that

Comment: Check firebug or something simular f12 in brouser and check network, what happanes there? What kind of error returns your request?

Comment: there is no error but i did't get the grid view , any way i had solve it now the problem is in document.ready function , when i remove that it will works fine ..